# Try/Except in Python

Tags: python, try-catch, except, try-except

My code is supposed to output:

```
Encipher
Enter 1 to encipher or 2 to decipher: 1
Enter text you wish to encipher: My dog has fleas.
Enter the number of characters to shift: 7
The encrypted text is: Fr whz atl yextl.
Decipher
Enter 1 to encipher or 2 to decipher: 2
Enter text you wish to decipher: Fr whz atl yextl.
The most likely shift is: 7
My dog has fleas.
```

But it doesn't work and I don't understand how to use try/except to make my code do this.

```
while True: 
    try: 
        num = int(raw_input('Enter 1 or 2:'))
        break
    except ValueError: 
        print "You have to enter 1 or 2, try again"

    if (num == 1):
        num = int(raw_input('Enter a number:'))
        num = int(raw_input('encipher'))
        print "Enter text to encipher"
        print "Enter the number of characters you want to shift" 

    elif (num == 2):
        num = int(raw_input('Enter a number:'))
        num = int(raw_input('decipher'))
        print "Enter text to decipher"
        print "Enter the number of characters you want to shift"
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? How is it not behaving like you expect?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  "It doesn't work" is not an accurate description.  The canonical response is, "That's because it's coded wrong."  :-)

Comment: if this line `num = int(raw_input('Enter 1 or 2:'))` is allowed (which will happen any time that the user inputs ANY integer , not just 1/2!) then `break` line will run which means that it will break out of the while loop. since the rest of your code is inside of your while loop, the rest of the code won't run. take out the break statement and add a `if num not in [1,2]: raise ValueError`

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that you don't get an except simply because the entered number doesn't match the text you printed.  Python does not automatically read and interpret the messages you send to the screen.  Instead, try this much at the top: go into an infinite loop that insists on legal data.  Keep going until you get legal data.  Grab each number, check to see whether it's legal; exit the loop if it fits your needs.

```
while True:
    while True:
        num = int(raw_input('Enter 1 or 2:'))
        if num in [1,2]:
            break
        print "You have to enter 1 or 2, try again"

    if (num == 1):
        ...
```

You're doing well to code only a few lines and get that working before you go on.  Do note that you have a few conceptual problems in the lower code.  For isntance, you ask the user to enter text to encipher, but then you try to convert that to integer.  *That* will get you ValueError.

Post a new question if you get stuck again.

Comment: few things. you're missing a try block around the input. and you should use in on a set instead of a list as its a faster lookup :)

Comment: Why not eliminate that nested `while` and just do `if num == 1:... elif num == 2:... else: print 'try again'`?

Comment: The inner loop gets legal input; the outer loop continues to encrypt and decrypt until the user dies and is laid in a crypt.

Comment: Right, but that doesn't need a nested loop. Note that the nested loop version ends up checking `num` twice.